# What will MutableSharedFlow in ViewModelScope do when an application goes into background and then starts again

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I am using the FirebaseAuthentication library and I want to be able to listen to changes to the authentication state regardless of what state the application is in. I want to use a SharedStateFlow with the viewModelLifecycle.  I'm choosing the viewModelScope because I want to avoid problems with configuration changes and duplicate collects.

If the application is in the Foreground the flow should run and collect as normal; where the FirebaseAuth listener - which is in my repository - dispatches an emission to the MutableSharedFlow and it is collected immediately in my ViewModel, which then navigates users back to the sign-in/sign-up page.

If the application is in the background; I expect that the AuthListener should still dispatch an event; because I am using a repository; with the repository being a singleton in the Application scope.  So an emission should still happen to the flow.  My expectation is that the flow should be hot; so it can still emit events; and then when the application goes back into the foreground the auth event should be collected and the application will navigate to the sign-in/sign-up page. I'm just using the collectLatest call in my ViewModel to subscribe to the events.

Is this the correct type of flow I should be using?  Should I be converting my flow into a LiveData object?

Comment: You're doing fine, you might want to use `replay=1`, because in case of no subscriber, `extraBufferCapacity` has no effect and even Listener fires event, `MutableSharedFlow` will not store it. If replaying causes problem, consider using Channel, items are consumed only once.